# How to scan a page using curl after the browser interpretation

Tags: javascript, php, curl, encryption

I need to scan a page but it is returning only the javascript to my curl call.

When I first load the page it first load the javascript and than the browser displays the html and the content.

the return I have:

```html
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/0851c0e08fab2000635c4968f73c790ee15b1914cdfc52e8e993db11b34b6a908f83b4ff6e1ec064?type=10"></script>

<script>

(function(){
    var securemsg;
    var dosl7_common;

window["blobfp"] = "11111111102000003e82493d514d300000000300000020http://re.security.f5aas.com/re/";


})();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/0851c0e08fab2000635c4968f73c790ee15b1914cdfc52e8e993db11b34b6a908f83b4ff6e1ec064?type=11"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
</head><body>
```

is there any way to scan the content of the page?

Thank you

Comment: If the page content is generated by Javascript, you cannot retrieve it other than by executing the Javascript. Period. Of course you can do that in a console without a full-fledged browser by installing a JS engine (like V8) and passing the code through it.

Comment: Good point @JohannesH. But just the V8 by node for example may not be enough if it needs the DOM

Comment: Yes, @Endless, you're correct of course. If a JS engine without a browser will be able to help depends on the JS code that is executed. It is possible that the DOM is not needed in this case however if the JS only loads HTML content and inserts it as a whole.

Comment: hi i have similar problem what approach you followed to scrap such websites successully

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like [ScrapeGoat](https://market.mashape.com/warting/scrapegoat) that will actually render the website in a browser and injects javascript that you use to respond back with.

There is some jsfiddle example [here](https://market.mashape.com/warting/scrapegoat/announcements)

```js
var fd = {
    url: prompt("url", "http://"),
    inject: `
      var body = document.querySelector("body").innerText;
      response.send(body);
    `
}

fetch("https://scrapegoat.p.mashape.com/", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(fd),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Mashape-Key": "dFYPWXxpp3mshKD6Kimb4pVfvYLvp1YWcWfjsnErOY3HN8zs4a"
  }
})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(text => {
  document.body.style.whiteSpace = "pre"
  document.body.innerText = text
})
```

You should probably get your own mashape key

it would look something like this

```
curl -X POST --include 'https://scrapegoat.p.mashape.com/' \
  -H 'X-Mashape-Key: <required>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"url":"http://example.com","inject":"response.send(document.querySelector("body").innerText);"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The curl request does not have a notion that it should wait for scripts on the page to execute. However, you could use a headless browser (i.e. [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)) to achieve your goal. With a headless browser, you have access to the D.O.M. and other properties of a real web browser, enabling you to get the data you want at any point in the life cycle of the page.

Comment: Do you have any example on how to use it inside my code?

Comment: The code you posted is not relevant to what I'm suggesting, so I can't make an example out of that. What you would have to do is use a headless browser to retrieve the information instead of using cURL. An example for that is going to depend on what server language and headless browser you are using. If you're knowledge is limited, go for the [approach suggested by Endless](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37709077/1666547).